# How to use temporary table in the from clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write a query to get the designation which has got the highest and second lowest amount (salary + variables)  for the whole year of 2019 along with the corresponding amount values.

```
Employees Table:

| Emp_id | first_name | Last_name | Salary |   Joining_date    | Department|
|:------ |:----------:|:---------:|:------:|:-----------------:|:---------:|
|  001   | Manish     |  Agarwal  | 700000 |2019-04-20 09:00:00|    HR     |
|  002   | Niranjan   |  Bose     | 20000  |2019-02-11 09:00:00|    DA     |
|  003   | Vivek      |  Singh    | 100000 |2019-01-20 09:00:00|    DA     |
|  004   | Asutosh    |  Kapoor   | 700000 |2019-03-20 09:00:00|    HR     |
|  005   | Vihaan     |  Banerjee | 300000 |2019-06-11 09:00:00|    DA     |
|  006   | Atul       |  Diwedi   | 400000 |2019-05-11 09:00:00|  Account  |
|  007   | Sathyendra |  Tripathi | 95000  |2019-03-20 09:00:00|  Account  |
|  008   | Prithika   |  Bhatt    | 95000  |2019-03-20 09:00:00|    DA     | 


Variables table:

| Emp_Ref_ID | Variables_Date     | Variables_amount|
|:---------- |:------------------:|:---------------:|
|     1      |2019-02-20 00:00:00 |    15000        | 
|     2      |2019-06-11 00:00:00 |    30000        | 
|     3      |2019-02-20 00:00:00 |    42000        | 
|     4      |2019-02-20 00:00:00 |    14500        | 
|     5      |2019-06-11 00:00:00 |    23500        | 


Designation table:

| Emp_Ref_ID | Emp_title      |    Affected_from   |
|:---------- |:--------------:|:------------------:|
|     1      |  Asst.Manager  |2019-02-20 00:00:00 | 
|     2      | Senior Analyst |2019-01-11 00:00:00 | 
|     8      | Senior Analyst |2019-04-06 00:00:00 | 
|     5      |     Manager    |2019-10-06 00:00:00 | 
|     4      |  Asst.Manager  |2019-12-06 00:00:00 | 
|     7      |  Team Lead     |2019-06-06 00:00:00 | 
|     6      |  Team Lead     |2019-09-06 00:00:00 | 
|     3      | Senior Analyst |2019-09-06 00:00:00 |
```

I tried the below query by creating a table called t1 and then fetching values from that

```
select emp_title , emp_ref_id from 
(select d.emp_ref_id , d.emp_title, e.salary+v.variables_amount as full_amount from employees e join variables_details v on 
e.emp_id = v.emp_ref_id join designation d on v.emp_ref_id=d.emp_ref_id) as t1
where t1.emp_ref_id in (select t1.emp_ref_id from t1 where full_amount = (select max(full_amount) from t1) or full_amount = (select min(full_amount)
from t1 limit 1 offset 1);
```

but the query throwed an error.

Later i decided to create a temporary table and then fetch the data from it. I used the below query:

```
create temporary table temp (select d.emp_ref_id , d.emp_title, e.salary+v.variables_amount as full_amount from employees e join 
variables_details v on e.emp_id = v.emp_ref_id join designation d on v.emp_ref_id=d.emp_ref_id);

select emp_title, full_amount from temp where full_amount = (select max(full_amount) from temp) or
full_amount =  (select full_amount from temp order by full_amount asc limit 1 offset 1);
```

But it throwed an error stating "cant reopen table temp".

Both the methods did not work for me .

How should i approach this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct indentation helps finding the missing parentesis

In mysql 8 you can use the With clause to generate t1

**Query #1**

```
WITH t1 AS (select d.emp_ref_id , d.emp_title, e.salary+v.variables_amount as full_amount 
      from employees e join variables_details v on e.emp_id = v.emp_ref_id 
      join designation d on v.emp_ref_id=d.emp_ref_id)
select emp_title , emp_ref_id 
from 
    t1
where t1.emp_ref_id in (select 
                             t1.emp_ref_id 
                             from t1 
                             where full_amount = (select max(full_amount) from t1) 
                                                  or full_amount = (select min(full_amount)
                                                                    from t1 limit 1 offset 1)
                        );
```

| emp_title | emp_ref_id |
| --- | --- |
| Asst.Manager | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/19)

With temporary tables this whole becomes more complicated

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORAry table  t1 (select d.emp_ref_id , d.emp_title, e.salary+v.variables_amount as full_amount 
>       from employees e join variables_details v on e.emp_id = v.emp_ref_id 
>       join designation d on v.emp_ref_id=d.emp_ref_id);
>       
> CREATE TEMPORAry table  t2 SELECT * FROM t1;
> CREATE TEMPORAry table  t3 SELECT * FROM t1;
> CREATE TEMPORAry table  t4 SELECT * FROM t1;
> ```

> ```
> select emp_title , emp_ref_id 
> from 
>   t1
> where emp_ref_id in (select 
>                              emp_ref_id 
>                              from t2
>                              where full_amount = (select max(full_amount) from  t3) 
>                                                   or full_amount = (select min(full_amount)
>                           from t4 limit 1 offset 1)
>                       );
> ```
>
> ```
> emp_title    | emp_ref_id
> :----------- | ---------:
> Asst.Manager |          1
> ```

> ```
> drop TEMPORAry table  t1;
> drop TEMPORAry table  t2;
> drop TEMPORAry table  t3;
> drop TEMPORAry table  t4;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5e65c36b36354ccde8473cc92054b1bb)*

Comment: i have changed the identation, now it throws an error stating "cant reopen table t1"

Comment: i add also a version with temporary tables

Comment: yes i have noted the temporary table method as well. Thanks a lot.